# How do I access properties or custom methods on a class in a view in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express

I do not know if this approach is wrong, if so please do tell, as I am new to NodeJs. But I am trying to achieve in Handlebars, to access a method. The way I have it structured is like this: I have a Series component which has the following:

- Series.js
- SeriesController.js
- SeriesDAL.js
- SeriesService.js

In the Series.js I have a function to get all series with simple select all, SQL. I then create a new instance of SeriesDAL, and wrap all the results around a SeriesDal class. Inside the SeriesDal, I wrap each result into a SeriesService.

Then I have a class of SeriesDal with an array of SeriesServices.

Now I have two problems

The first is my result set looks like this:

```
SeriesDal {
  series: 
   [ SeriesService { serie: [Object] },
     SeriesService { serie: [Object] } ] }
```

Which means in my view I have to do a loop inside of a loop to reach the series.

Can I somehow reach something that looks like this:

```
SeriesDal {
   [ SeriesService { [Object] },
     SeriesService { [Object] } ] }
So that I only have to loop through it once?
```

The second thing is, now in my view, in my loop I am on the SeriesService entry, and let's say I have a custom getLinkRef How would I access this getLinkRef method/property

Example of the code I have currently made: https://pastebin.com/C2fupLye

Thanks in advance hope someone can give me a hand here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've created a lot of complexity with this DAL and Service layer which has caused some confusion.

If you want SeriesService to have all the properties that your SeriesService.serie has, then just assign all of those properties to the Service in it's constructor. This will give

```
function SeriesService(serie) {
    // Ditch the this.serie object which is causing your layer of nesting
    this.link = serie.link;
    this.name = serie.name;
    // Etc...
}

SeriesService.prototype.getLinkRef = function() {
    // Now this can access everything via "this" and it should be valid
    return "<a href='" . this.link . "'>" . this.name . "</a>";
};

module.exports = SeriesService;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you appreciate it! I'll try to look into not confusing myself with to many layers :)

Comment: Judging by your naming convention, I'm assuming you come from a C# or Java background where "DAL" and "Service" are common place. JavaScript is a very flexible language, I personally write my code functionally which might be something to look into for the long term (not if you're beginning with JS or Node).

Just using functions and grouping them into modules can often reduce complexity and thought space a lot.

That said it can be a lot to get your head around after coming from OO like I did.